# Mysql query not optimized and very slow, but why?

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, optimization, innodb

in the software that i develop, a car delear software,  there's a section with the agenda with all the appointments of the users.

This section is pretty fast to load with a daily and normal use of the agenda, thousands of rows,  but start to be really slow when the agenda tables reach 1 million of rows.

The structure:

1) Main table

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `agenda` (
  `id_agenda` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `id_user` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `id_agency` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `id_customer` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `id_car` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `id_owner` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `type` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '8',
  `title` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `text` text NOT NULL,
  `start_day` date NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00',
  `end_day` date NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00',
  `start_hour` time NOT NULL DEFAULT '00:00:00',
  `end_hour` time NOT NULL DEFAULT '00:00:00'
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_agenda`),
  KEY `start_day` (`start_day`),
  KEY `id_customer` (`id_customer`),
  KEY `id_car` (`id_car`),
  KEY `id_user` (`id_user`),
  KEY `id_owner` (`id_owner`),
  KEY `type` (`type`),
  KEY `id_agency` (`id_agency`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 ;
```

2) Secondary table

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `agenda_cars` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `id_agenda` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `id_car` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `id_owner` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `id_agenda` (`id_agenda`),
  KEY `id_car` (`id_car`),
  KEY `id_owner` (`id_owner`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

---

Query:

```
SELECT a.id_agenda
FROM agenda as a
LEFT JOIN agenda_cars as agc on agc.id_agenda = a.id_agenda
WHERE 
(a.id_customer = '22'  OR (a.id_owner = '22' OR agc.id_owner = '22' ))
GROUP BY a.id_agenda
ORDER BY a.start_day,  a.start_hour
```

Explain:

```
id  select_type table   type    possible_keys  key         key_len    ref   rows    Extra   
1   SIMPLE       a      index   PRIMARY        PRIMARY      4          NULL 1051987 Using temporary; Using filesort
1   SIMPLE       agc    ref     id_agenda      id_agenda    4   db.a.id_agenda  1   Using where
```

The query reachs 10 secs to end, with the id 22, but with other id can reach also 20 secs, this just for the query, to load all in the web page take of course more time.

I don't get the point why it takes so long to get the data, i think the indexes are right configured and the query is pretty simple, so why?

Too much data?

I've solved in this way:

```
SELECT a.id_agenda
  FROM
      (
              SELECT id_agenda
              FROM agenda  
              WHERE (id_customer = '22'  OR  id_owner = '22' )
          UNION
              SELECT id_agenda
              FROM  agenda_cars
              WHERE id_owner = '22'
      )  as at
INNER JOIN agenda as a on a.id_agenda = at.id_agenda
GROUP BY a.id_agenda
ORDER BY a.start_day,  a.start_hour
```

This version of the query is ten times faster the then previous...but why?

### Thanks to all want to contribute to solve my doubts!

**UPDATE AFTER Rick James solution:**

Query suggested

```
SELECT  a.id_agenda
    FROM  
    (
        SELECT  id_agenda  FROM  agenda  WHERE  id_customer = '22'
        UNION DISTINCT
        SELECT  id_agenda  FROM  agenda  WHERE  id_owner = '22'
        UNION DISTINCT
        SELECT  id_agenda  FROM  agenda_cars  WHERE  id_owner = '22'
    ) as at
    INNER JOIN  agenda as a  ON a.id_agenda = at.id_agenda
    ORDER BY  a.start_datetime;
```

Result: 279 total, 0.0111 sec

EXPLAIN:

```
id      select_type     table           type    possible_keys   key         key_len     ref             rows        Extra
1       PRIMARY         <derived2>      ALL     NULL            NULL        NULL        NULL            366         Using temporary; Using filesort
1       PRIMARY         a               eq_ref  PRIMARY         PRIMARY     4           at.id_agenda    1           NULL
2       DERIVED         agenda          ref     id_customer     id_customer 5           const           1           Using index
3       UNION           agenda          ref     id_owner        id_owner    5           const           114         Using index
4       UNION           agenda_cars     ref     id_owner        id_owner    4           const           250         NULL
NULL    UNION RESULT    <union2,3,4>    ALL     NULL            NULL        NULL        NULL            NULL        Using temporary
```

Comment: You order by columns that don't have an index

Comment: `OR` queries tend to confound the MySQL optimizer, breaking them up into `UNION` is the usual solution.

Comment: Some observations: You have a GROUP BY clause with no aggregating functions. You LEFT JOIN a table from which you select no columns.

Comment: `OR` in a query is the kiss of death. Often this means creating temporary tables and collating records which is always a messy ordeal.

Comment: @juergend - The only way for the `ORDER BY` to use an index is for the `WHERE` and `GROUP BY` to already be fully handled by that same index.  Not possible here -- if for no other reason than the `GROUP BY` and `ORDER BY` list different columns.

Comment: @tadman -- or using `UNION`, as he partially did.  No temp table other than the one that `UNION` will implicitly create.

Answer (score 3):

Before I dig into what can be done, let me list several reg flags I see.

- `OR` is hard to optimize
- Filtering (`WHERE`) on multiple tables `JOINed` together is hard to optimize.
- `GROUP BY x ORDER BY z` means two passes over the data, usually 2 temp tables and filesorts.
- Did you really mean `LEFT`?  It says "the right table (`agc`) might be missing, in which case provide `NULLs`".

(You may not be able to get rid of all of the red flags.)

Red flags in the Schema:

- Indexing every column -- usually not useful
- Only single-column indexes -- "composite" indexes often help.
- `DATE` and `TIME` as separate columns -- *usually* makes for clumsy queries.

OK, those are off my shoulder, now to study the query...  (Oh, and thanks for providing the `CREATEs` and `EXPLAIN`!)

The `ON` implies a 1:many relationship between agenda:agenda_cars.  Is that correct?

`id_owner` and `id_car` are in both tables, yet are not included in the `ON`; what's up?

(Here's the meat of the answer to your final question.)  Why have `GROUP BY`?  I see no aggregates.  I will guess that the 1:many relationship lead to multiple rows, and you needed to de-dup?  For dedupping, please use `DISTINCT`.  But, the real solution is to avoid the "inflate (`JOIN`) - deflate (`GROUP BY`)" syndrome.  Your subquery is a good start on that.

Rolling some of the above comments in, plus more:

```
SELECT  a.id_agenda
    FROM  
    (
        SELECT  id_agenda  FROM  agenda  WHERE  id_customer = '22'
        UNION DISTINCT
        SELECT  id_agenda  FROM  agenda  WHERE  id_owner = '22'
        UNION DISTINCT
        SELECT  id_agenda  FROM  agenda_cars  WHERE  id_owner = '22'
    ) as at
    INNER JOIN  agenda as a  ON a.id_agenda = at.id_agenda
    ORDER BY  a.start_datetime;
```

Notes:

- Got rid of the other `OR`
- Explicit `UNION DISTINCT` to be clear that dups are expected.
- Toss `GROUP BY` and not using `SELECT DISTINCT`; `UNION DISTINCT` deals with the need.
- You have the 4 necessary indexes (one per subquery): `(id_customer)`, `(id_owner)` (on both tables) and `PRIMARY KEY(id_agenda)`.
- The indexes are "covering indexes for all the subqueries -- an extra bonus.
- There will be *one* unavoidable tmp table and file sort -- for the `ORDER BY`, but it won't be on a million rows.
- (No need for composite indexes -- this time.)
- I changed to a `DATETIME`; change back if you have a good reason for splitting them.

Did I get you another 10x?  Did I explain it sufficiently?

Oh, one more thing...

This query returns an list of ids ordered by something that it does not return (date+time).  What will you do with ids?  If you are using this as a subquery in another table, then the Optimizer has a right to throw away the `ORDER BY`.  Just warning you.

Comment: first of all thanks for your help.
I try to explain better the structure: 
- agenda is the main table, inside this table you see id_car, id_owner cause at the beginning ( first version of the software, it was possible to link just one car and one owner to the appointement, after i added the possibility to link more than one car / owner to agenda, so the agenda_cars tables comes in.
I have to use left join cause i 've to preserve the compatibility with the old version.

Comment: - i added indexes for all the field used by "where" clause, if i use composite index, am i able to do that? or i always need to use the left most fields of the composite index?

Comment: i need to add group by cause i can have more than one cars linked to one row of agenda, and also the order by is done for a list order by time asc for the customer.

I tried your suggestion to use "distinct" inside the unions, i tried also to create a composite index (start_day, start_hour)  for covering the order by, but i don't have an increase of speed.
Thanks again for the help!

Comment: @Jung - `LEFT` allows for 0 (or more) cars; `JOIN` allows for 1 or more.

Comment: In using `WHERE a=1 OR b=2`, no index is useful.  For `WHERE a=1 AND b=2`, `INDEX(a,b)` (in either order) is best; `INDEX(a)` or `INDEX(b)` are each somewhat useful.

Comment: See my [_cookbook_](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql) .  `INDEX(start_day...)` is not useful for complex reasons; see that link.

Comment: Have you tried my variant?  Did it run faster and not have dups?

Comment: Yes i tried your variant, the result it's the same, i don't have dups and the speed is the same of the query with the GROUP BY outside the union, also the explain is totally equal.
Thinking about the query above, variant 1 or variant 2 (your), the UNION is already checking for dups so i was thinking that DISTINCT or GROUP BY are necessary at the end, right?
Thanks for the link of cookbook, i'll read it for sure!

Comment: No, there would be 5 lines in the Explain; please post it.

Comment: i posted the explain in my answer ;-)

Comment: Good.  The numbers in the `EXPLAIN` are reasonable -- a few hundred rows, not a million.  You say the "speed is the same"?   I can't believe 10-20 seconds for the `UNION` version.